# How to use functions

Tags: php, functions

I have installed the plugin WPdeposit on my site, it allows users to deposit into their account balance. I am trying to manipulate users balances when they press an anchor tag on the page.

In the directory plugins/models/user.php there are many functions, I think im interested in this one:

```
 /**
 * Update Regular balance to given amount (Will overwrite whatever value is in the db!)
 *
 * @param int $amount
 * @return boolean
 */
public function updateRegularBalance($amount) {
    if (floatval($amount)) {
        return (bool) update_user_meta($this->_id, WPDEPOSIT_NAME.self::USER_AMOUNT, $amount);
    } else {
        throw new \Exception(__('Amount is not a number', WPDEPOSIT_NAME));
    }
}
```

when I try to call this function to the page on the theme's index.php like so:

```
updateRegularBalance(5);
```

but I receive this error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function updateRegularBalance()

is there a way to access the use of this function so I can pass in the value I want to update the balance to?

Comment: `updateRegularBalance` is not a function, it is a method inside a class. You need to instantiate the class and then use the method, like `$class = new TheClassName(); $class->updateRegularBalance(5);`

Comment: Well that is important info, 36 hours and you solved it right away. Thank you. Do you know of any good resources I can read to review more on this subject. Thank you!

Comment: You need to look into OOP and how classes are constructed and how you should make use of class methods and properties.

Comment: maybe you'll want to check out the [action hooks of WPdeposit](http://docs.uwebic.com/products/wpdeposit) to see if you could go with [hooking your function to an action exposed by the plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) instead of instanciating the plugin class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the current method would be to create the object then call the method:

```
$objClassName = new ClassName();
$var = $objClassName->updateRegularBalance(5);
```

Another way would be to make the method static since the class has no private data(In your case) to rely on:

```
public static function updateRegularBalance($amount){}
```

This can then be called like so:

```
$var = ClassName::updateRegularBalance(5);
```

As of *PHP 5.3.0*, it's possible to reference the class using a variable. The variable's value can not be a keyword (e.g. self, parent and static).

Lastly, you do not need a class and can just have a file of functions which you include. So you remove the class *ClassName* and the public in the method.

Have a look at the PHP manual section on [Object Oriented programming](http://php.net/oop).

Let me know in case of any concern.